# how to enable package apk to bar in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, blackberry, android-studio-plugin

First i have generated a signed APK and place it in the app folder inside your project directory. But "package apk to bar " option was not highlighted in android studio.

I restarted my android studio and i again install blackberry plugin too.
But it is not working.

Any one help me.

compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.3'
android studio version: 2.2

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Maybe this can help you, you can start BlackBerry APK Packager directly with exe file:

> %LOCATION_OF_ANDROID_STUDIO%\config\plugins\BlackBerry_Idea_Plugin_for_Android_Development\BlackBerry
>   APK Packager.exe

I hope it will help you